# How to copy values from other dataframe based on condition (same values of specific column)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2) and they look like this:

```
data1 = {'col1':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], 'col2':np.arange(1,13)*2}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'x': [1,2,3,4], 'y': [10,20,40,5]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I would like to add a new column 'col3' to df1 with the values of df2['y'] when df1['col1'] is equal to df2['x']. So my df1 would stay like:

```
col1    col2    col3
1      2      10
2      4      20
3      6      40
4      8      5
1      10     10
2      12     20
3      14     40
4      16     5
1      18     10
2      20     20
3      22     40
4      24     5
```

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` with the dictionary creating from `df2`

```
df1['col3'] = df1.col1.map(dict(df2[['x', 'y']].values))
```

or

```
df1['col3'] = df1.col1.map(dict(zip(df2.x, df2.y)))

Out[886]:
    col1  col2  col3
0      1     2    10
1      2     4    20
2      3     6    40
3      4     8     5
4      1    10    10
5      2    12    20
6      3    14    40
7      4    16     5
8      1    18    10
9      2    20    20
10     3    22    40
11     4    24     5
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy. This is a example of a bigger dataframe. Imagine that I have more columns in df2 and just want to add the values of df2['y']. So if I have more columns, I can't use your exactly code. How can I specify these columns on your code?

Comment: @LucasA: just use slicing of 2 columns you want to map. I edited my answer. Please check updated

Comment: @LucasA: or `zip` 2 columns to create dictionary

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use a `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='col1', right_on='x') \
    [['col1', 'col2', 'y']] \
    .rename(columns={'y': 'col3'})
```